# Show toast prior to a for loop does not work

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, android-toast

I am trying to show a toast prior to a for loop, however, the toast does not show. I also tried adding a snackbar, but that didn't work either. I would like to know why the toast does not fire first. I even tried the following, but it kept looping:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
while (!toast.getView().isShown()) {
    toast.show();
}
```

How can I show a toast prior to a for loop?

```
ArrayList<String> pizzaBases = new ArrayList<> ();    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            });

            SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                try {
                    String pizza = preferences.getString("TypeOfBase" + i, "");
                    if (!pizza.equals("")) {
                        pizzaBases.add(pizza);
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    //Do nothing here
                }
            }
        }
    });

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonOne);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            for (String myString : pizzaBases) {
                System.out.println(myString);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I tried solutions like runOnUiThread, asynctask and while loops, but they all didn't show a toast nor a snackbar.

**EDIT:**

I found out that the UI only updates AFTER the for loop is done. I am wondering why it does that, although it is activated first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Toast.show()` is asynchronous. The toast will not be displayed until the current method returns, and even then, Android may decide to show it at a later time (for example if there is already another toast displayed on the screen) or even not at all.

Do you really need to use the native toasts? Maybe the best would be to use another system that is more reliable. What about a custom view that appears on top of everything that looks like a toast and that you can show immediately and reliably?

Comment: I would like to tell the user that the function is succesfully fired when he clicks the button. It is neccessary, as the user has to wait and I would like to address him why. In this example it is "Hello", but in the release it will be a different message.

Comment: If it is important that the user sees the message immediately, then you shouldn't rely on toasts. I would suggest integrating it somewhere in your UI, for example by showing the message in a TextView or changing the text of the button when the user clicks on it (some websites do that, they disable the button and the text changes to "Sending..." along with a progress indicator). But how to implement it is more of a UX question. You could also use something like Crouton : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.keyboardsurfer.app.demo.crouton

Comment: I checked, and found out that the UI only updates after the for loop, although it fires before the for loop..

Comment: Any idea why and how to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is how android works. All UI updates are done when the current method finishes (here, `onCreate`). If you want to run your for loop after that the UI has been updated, you should use an AysncTask. In `onPreExecute()` you put the code that updates the UI and in `doInBackground()` you run the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling show() method on this line:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

It should be:

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I am calling .show(), I forgot to copy it with the code I provided

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `runOnUiThread` cause you're already on the main thread and you're not calling `show()` on your toast in the second code.
It's also better to pass in the nearest `Context` object to your toast.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
        Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // show must be called
        Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am calling .show(), I forgot to copy it with the code I provided. I will look into it!

Comment: Prior to getApplicationContext I used MainActivity.this, and it unfortunately did not work either.

Comment: @Jason Are you sure your `onClick` is even called? Put a break point in there and check if it reaches the `onClick` method.

Comment: Yes it is called, as a I see the effects of the for loop. If I click on another button, I System.out the ArrayList, and I can obviously see the contents.

Answer (score 0):

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);`

- When you are show toast you have to call `.show()` method.
- If you are showing `Toast` in `Activity` it will be better to use `Activity` 's `context`

**Correction**

`Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

---

`Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

If you want to show `SnackBar` than you have to provide the view of current activity not `android.R.id.content`

**Correction**

`Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.parent_of_your_activity), "Had a snack at Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

---

- You don't need to use `runOnUiThread` cause you're already on the main thread
- You can get `Context`

  1. via `YourActivity.this` or `this` in `Activity` itself
  2. via `getContext()` in `Fragment` class

Comment: The snackbar was just to check If a snackbar would work but a toast does not. I am calling .show(), I forgot to copy it over when creating this question.